# mySQL Subquery to Stored Procedure or JPA query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

(Edit 1: not Date but wc_Event.date)
I created a query (with subquery) that executes perfectly but I have trouble converting it either to a JPA query or a stored procedure.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM wc_Event WHERE (wc_Event.date > CURRENT_DATE())
AND wc_Event.evt_id IN
( 
    SELECT event_users.evt_id FROM event_users
    WHERE event_users.usr_id = 1
)
ORDER BY wc_Event.date
```

I have tried this for stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getFutureRegistredEvents
(
    my_user_id int    
)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM wc_Event WHERE (wc_Event.date > CURRENT_DATE())
AND wc_Event.evt_id IN
( 
    SELECT event_users.evt_id FROM event_users
    WHERE event_users.usr_id = my_user_id
)
ORDER BY wc_Event.date
END
```

It tells me to use the right syntax at line 13 (= END) but even if I add a semicolon to it my query wont work.

I also tried creating the same effect with JPA queries but with no effect.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance
Bert

Comment: You didn't put the semicolon at the end of your SELECT statement. And you have to change your DELIMITER when creating a stored procedure, put at the beggining `DELIMITER //` and at the end `DELIMITER ;`